# Multiplying an entire df or matrix by 1000?

Tags: python, r, pandas

I am new to R and Python, so forgive me if this is an elementary question. I have a large data set of genes (columns) by patients (rows), with each value being an RNA expression value (most values falling between 0 and 1). I want to multiply the entire data set by 1000 so that all non-zero values will be >1.

Currently:

```r
Pt GeneA GeneB GeneC
 1  0.001   2     0    
 2    0    0.5  0.002
```

Would like:

```r
Pt GeneA GeneB GeneC
 1    1   2000   0    
 2    0   500    2
```

I have tried to do this in both R and Python and am running into issues with both. I have also tried converting my data between data frame and matrix, and it won't work with either. I have searched extensively on this website and find information about how to multiply an entire df/matrix by a vector, or individual columns by a scalar, but not the entire thing. Could someone kindly point me in the right direction? I feel like it can't possibly be this hard :)

**Using R:**

```r
df <- read.csv("/Users/m/Desktop/data.csv")
df * 100
```

> ```
> In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘*’ not meaningful for factors
> ```

```r
mtx <- as.matrix(df)
mtx * 100
```

> ```
> Error in mtx * 100 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
> ```

**Using Python 3.7.6:**

```py
df = df * 1000
```

^ This runs without an error message but the values in the cells are exactly the same, so it didn't actually multiply anything...

```py
df = df.div(.001)
```

> ```
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'
> ```

Any creative ideas or resources to point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: Your dataframe contains string. You can do `'a'*1000` in python, which repeat the string `1000` times, but you can't *divide* a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does `str(df)` give you? At least some of your columns have been converted to factors because they are character strings. Open the csv file in a text editor and make sure the numbers are not surrounded by "" or that missing values have been labeled with a character. Once you have the data read properly it will be simple:

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(matrix(sample.int(100, 100, replace=TRUE), 10, 10))
str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  10 variables:
#  $ X1 : int  49 65 25 74 100 18 49 47 24 71
#  $ X2 : int  100 89 37 20 26 3 41 89 27 36
#  $ X3 : int  95 5 84 34 92 3 58 97 42 24
#  $ X4 : int  30 43 15 22 58 8 36 68 86 18
#  $ X5 : int  92 69 4 98 50 99 88 87 49 26
#  $ X6 : int  6 6 2 3 21 2 58 10 40 5
#  $ X7 : int  33 49 100 73 29 76 84 9 35 93
#  $ X8 : int  16 92 69 92 2 82 24 18 69 55
#  $ X9 : int  40 21 100 57 100 42 18 91 13 53
#  $ X10: int  54 83 32 80 60 29 81 73 85 43
dat1000 <- dat * 1000
```

Comment: Yes! For whatever reason, the df structure was all factors. I ran lapply through every column with as.numeric(as.character(x)) and now I can manipulate it without a problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try this option:

```
df[,c(2:ncol(df)] <- 1000*df[,c(2:ncol(df)]
```

If you instead wanted a perhaps more generic solution targeting only columns whose name starts with `Gene`, then use:

```
df[grep("^Gene", names(df))] <- 1000*df[grep("^Gene", names(df))]
```

Comment: Ah, I thought this was going to work! Error: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50). In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘*’ not meaningful for factors. I used as.numeric(as.character(df)) and applied your answer and it turned everything to "NA"? Sigh.

Comment: It sounds like some of the columns you are multipying are, for some reason, factor.  Numeric columns should not be factor.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your target result, you need to multiply all columns except pt. In python:

```py
target_cols = [i for i in df.columns if i!='Pt']
for i in target_cols:
  df[i] = df[i].astype(float)
  df[i] = df[i]*1000
```

Comment: This may work well but it is trying to apply it to my first row (gene names). "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'A1BG'" If I define target_cols and then use target_cols=target_cols.drop(target_cols.rows[[0]], axis=0) and then run the for loop, could I somehow recover the gene names for use later?

Comment: @desert007 if you have some column names you don't want to do this transformation to, add then to: target_cols = [i for i in df.columns if i not in ['Pt', 'Gene1', 'Gene2']]. These columns will still be retained but not transformed

Comment: Yes, but how would I retain but not transform the column names for all columns? The column names (row 1) are character/strings and it is causing issues with .astype(float)

Comment: @desert007 In the code, I am doing the transformations only on the target_cols. Add all the columns with string characters to ['Pt', 'Gene1', 'Gene2'] list in above comment and run the for loop. You will see that astype(float) is not done on those string columns